# Using NSolve for the complex equation

Tags: equation-solving

I try to solve the complex equations, which are

```
eqs={(0. + 0. I) + (12782.4 + 440.168 I) x1 + (0.283992 - 
 204.889 I) x2 + (0.113597 - 81.9557 I) x4 + (0.0730265 - 
 52.6858 I) x6 + (11.506 + 0.38002 I) y1 - (2280.69 + 
 75.3268 I) y2 - (0.244509 + 0.00807566 I) y3 + (1904.23 + 
 62.8932 I) y4 - (61.182 + 2.02073 I) y5 + (1983.44 + 
 65.5092 I) y6, (0. + 
0. I) - (0.283992 - 204.889 I) x1 + (52765.8 + 
 1765.21 I) x2 + (0.511186 - 368.801 I) x3 + (0.202851 - 
 146.35 I) x5 - (806.641 + 26.6418 I) y1 - (50.3164 + 
 1.66185 I) y2 - (7981.11 + 263.601 I) y3 + (61.2852 + 
 2.02413 I) y4 + (3323.88 + 109.782 I) y5 - (94.9258 + 
 3.13522 I) y6, (0. + 
0. I) - (0.511186 - 368.801 I) x2 + (119405. + 
 3973.6 I) x3 + (0.730265 - 526.858 I) x4 + (0.283992 - 
 204.889 I) x6 - (16.1792 + 0.534367 I) y1 - (4104.22 + 
 135.555 I) y2 - (22.8649 + 0.755183 I) y3 - (16754.4 + 
 553.366 I) y4 + (165.358 + 5.46148 I) y5 + (4213.74 + 
 139.172 I) y6, (0. + 
0. I) - (0.113597 - 81.9557 I) x1 - (0.730265 - 
 526.858 I) x3 + (212699. + 7065.36 I) x4 + (0.94664 - 
 682.964 I) x5 + (5863.38 + 193.656 I) y1 + (37.9452 + 
 1.25326 I) y2 - (8624.58 + 284.854 I) y3 + (24.4971 + 
 0.809092 I) y4 - (27846.6 + 919.72 I) y5 + (246.661 + 
 8.14675 I) y6, (0. + 
0. I) - (0.202851 - 146.35 I) x2 - (0.94664 - 
 682.964 I) x4 + (332650. + 11040.5 I) x5 + (1.16179 - 
 838.184 I) x6 - (87.7843 + 2.89935 I) y1 + (12719.3 + 
 420.094 I) y2 + (108.299 + 3.57691 I) y3 - (14408.3 + 
 475.878 I) y4 + (28.6819 + 0.947308 I) y5 - (40292.5 + 
 1330.79 I) y6, (0. + 
0. I) - (0.0730265 - 52.6858 I) x1 - (0.283992 - 
 204.889 I) x3 - (1.16179 - 838.184 I) x5 + (479255. + 
 15898.9 I) x6 + (2114.16 + 69.8268 I) y1 - (158.082 + 
 5.22116 I) y2 + (21071.4 + 695.947 I) y3 + (142.35 + 
 4.70154 I) y4 - (20971.9 + 692.662 I) y5 + (29.1607 + 
 0.963123 I) y6, (11.507 - 0.336004 I) x1 - (806.385 + 
 211.577 I) x2 - (16.1882 - 5.98378 I) x3 + (5863.24 + 
 292.371 I) x4 - (87.7771 + 10.0382 I) x5 + (2114.12 + 
 105.155 I) x6 + (262.903 + 35.0466 I) y1 + (192.202 - 
 514.005 I) y2 - (448.711 - 23.5559 I) y3 - (22.6567 + 
 139.531 I) y4 - (1306.6 + 72.2709 I) y5 - (33.8355 + 
 63.2813 I) y6, (-2280.71 - 56.9965 I) x1 - (50.3238 - 
 1.78186 I) x2 - (4103.89 + 374.739 I) x3 + (37.9403 + 
 4.72454 I) x4 + (12719. + 594.212 I) x5 - (158.063 + 
 19.1109 I) x6 - (9.74243 - 513.29 I) y1 + (4807.9 + 
 190.193 I) y2 + (480.63 - 848.382 I) y3 - (345.884 - 
 39.8563 I) y4 - (63.3348 + 264.847 I) y5 - (2674.52 + 
 159.864 I) y6, (-0.245646 + 0.781608 I) x1 - (7981.16 + 
 229.964 I) x2 - (22.8682 - 1.57708 I) x3 - (8624.2 + 
 562.048 I) x4 + (108.301 + 2.29845 I) x5 + (21071. + 
 964.38 I) x6 - (448.664 + 10.4838 I) y1 + (147.314 + 
 847.538 I) y2 + (18487. + 639.403 I) y3 + (830.618 - 
 1174.95 I) y4 - (222.942 - 45.6112 I) y5 - (95.6662 + 
 388.625 I) y6, (1904.32 - 0.644351 I) x1 + (61.2853 + 
 1.91342 I) x2 - (16754.5 + 484.522 I) x3 + (24.496 - 
 0.445743 I) x4 - (14407.9 + 770.308 I) x5 + (142.354 + 
 3.09075 I) x6 - (77.467 - 140.147 I) y1 - (345.837 - 
 3.57019 I) y2 + (369.4 + 1171.41 I) y3 + (47410.4 + 
 1579.78 I) y4 + (1293.26 - 1494.99 I) y5 + (187.234 + 
 69.6006 I) y6, (-61.1854 + 0.363002 I) x1 + (3324.05 - 
 10.2592 I) x2 + (165.36 + 2.17904 I) x3 - (27846.8 + 
 791.273 I) x4 + (28.684 - 0.881789 I) x5 - (20971.5 + 
 1002.27 I) x6 - (1306.64 + 44.3326 I) y1 - (167.649 - 
 265.838 I) y2 - (222.903 - 16.844 I) y3 + (706.889 + 
 1487.88 I) y4 + (100895. + 3330.35 I) y5 + (1899.09 - 
 1810.88 I) y6, (1983.53 + 0.366697 I) x1 - (94.9274 + 
 0.382036 I) x2 + (4213.96 - 17.912 I) x3 + (246.667 + 
 3.57876 I) x4 - (40292.8 + 1135.49 I) x5 + (29.1622 - 
 1.2498 I) x6 - (59.8511 - 67.1936 I) y1 - (2674.61 + 
 94.62 I) y2 - (248.696 - 389.448 I) y3 + (187.285 + 
 42.5579 I) y4 + (1188.94 + 1801.53 I) y5 + (190130. + 
 6258.29 I) y6};
```

There are twelve variables, including x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, and y6.

Using NSolve,

```
NSolve[Thread[eqs == 0], {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6}]
```

we obtain

```
{{x1 -> 0, x2 -> 0, x3 -> 0, x4 -> 0, x5 -> 0, x6 -> 0, y1 -> 0, y2 -> 0, y3 -> 0, y4 -> 0, y5 -> 0, y6 -> 0}}
```

In fact, the solution to the complex equations should be complex. Now the question is how do I find the complex solution.

I has tried to add the command to solve the equations in the complex field or use the function `FindRoot`. The solution is still zero.

Comment: I tried `NSolve[......, Complexes]`, to no avail.

Comment: Unless we change `(0. + 0. I)`, otherwise, only zero solution in this linear equation.

Comment: @cvgmt     Could you please explain it more detail?

Comment: `Array[a, {12, 12}] . Array[x, 12] == Array[b, 12]` only zero solution when `Array[a, {12, 12}]` is not a singular matrix and `Array[b, 12]` is a zeror vecotr.